# Formatting output to a file

Tags: java, logging

I have a class method that logs output to a file and I want more control over format specifying.

```
public class Logger {

    private static boolean FIRST_CALL = true;

    public static void log(String content) {



        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("debug.txt", !FIRST_CALL)));

            if(FIRST_CALL) {
                FIRST_CALL = false;
            }

            out.println(content);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not sure how to go about it. changing `println` to `printf` creates a whole host of problems.

E.g I call the method as follows:

```
Logger.log("testval=" + testVal);
```

Where `testVal` would be a `double` for example. It would output `1.9547E-5` but I actually want it in decimal format instead.

Any help appreciated. I'm new to Java.

Comment: `printf`, `format` should be your first choice, as they offer precise flexibility of output strings

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class.

You can do something like

```
Logger.log(MessageFormat.format("testval={0}", testVal));
```

Like printf you can configure the format of your output. See the Javadoc for all the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.format()`.
In your example:

```
Logger.log(String.format("testval=%f", testVal));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if to fix your code for a double, I'd write in this way:

```
 private void log(double )
 {
      // use try-with-resource - it's better
      try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("debug.txt", !FIRST_CALL))))
      {
          if(FIRST_CALL) {
              FIRST_CALL = false;
          }

          out.printf("value = %5.7f\n", d);
          out.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
 }
```

and call this code:

```
   log(1.9547E-5)
```